# Destroy an async void

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin and C#. When I destroy an activity I observe that async void is still running.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.TableItemsMain);
    RefreshTableAsync();
}

async Task RefreshTableAsync()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000);
        var response = await client.PostAsync("http://" + MyIp + ":9090/", new StringContent("2:" + MyTableName + "", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        }
    }
}
```

How can I dispose my async void on destroy?

Comment: Normally, when you dispose an object the descendant objects will also be disposed by the GC. However; if any descandant object is still alive, GC will not destroy the object. In your case; I would try using async Task alternatives of methods and await for the task to end. Async void fucntion may somehow hang by any exception which you cannot handle by using like this.

Comment: You should cancel all your background threads related to that activities lifecycle so use a Cancellationtoken with your HttpClient's PostAsync and then during dispose you can review the state and request that the Post is cancelled (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh943637%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: The closest thing to what you want is to use `CancellationToken` as described by @SushiHangover. Since the async cancellation is cooperative approach, there will be no guarantees when it will happen (might not be respected so could not happen at all).

Comment: Anyway, even if you decide not to use cancellation,
you probably should check if the activity is dead after each await and, if so, abort any further processing. Also, wrap this code in `try...catch`, http calls have a pretty much great chance of failing.

Comment: How can i call my async task in my example and how should i cancel it?